# Using bash script, how do I concatenate text to rename a file?

Tags: bash, unix

Let's say I have a file in the form:

> randomstuff.extension_filename_more_random_stuff.extension

and I want to change the file name to just:

> filename.extension

What bash script could I write to rename the file to the format above where the name is in between the first and second underscore and the (unknown) file extension remains the same?

Edit:

Here's an example...
I want to change a file called:

> myfile.java_HelloWorld_Created_2020-02-25-08-08-17_myfile.java

to:

> HelloWorld.java

Another example:

Input:

> notes.txt_history_Created_2020-02-25-08-08-17_notes.txt

Desired output:

> history.txt

Edit part 2:
Here is the code I currently have:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir=${1}

if [[ ! -d $dir ]]; then
    echo "Enter a valid directory path"
    exit 0
fi

cd $dir/

for f in *; do
    newf=$(echo "$f" | cut -f 1 -d '_')
    echo $newf
done
```

My output is:

```
myfile.java
notes.txt
```

which is not the desired output. I also haven't figured out how to rename files yet.

Comment: What does this have to do with concatenation? What do you mean by that?

Comment: What I am trying to do is concatenate the text between the first and second underscore in the file name with the extension, as shown in the examples above.

Comment: `where the name is in between the first and second underscore` research `cut`. `the (unknown) file extension remains the same?` There should be multiple questions on this forum how to extract extension from filename. Research it.

Comment: ...eh, I wouldn't really recommend `cut`; running an external command for something the shell can do itself is not ideal. Pretty much everything here can be done with [parameter expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution that works as I want it to:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=${1}

if [[ ! -d $dir ]]; then
    echo "Enter a valid directory path"
    exit 0
fi

cd $dir/

for f in *; do
    newn=$(echo "$f" | cut -f 2 -d '_')
    ext=${file##*.}
    newf=$newn.$ext
    mv $f $newf
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use ´awk´ for that: ´awk´ is very well suited for splitting strings into substrings, based on separators, as in the following example:

```
echo randomstuff.extension_filename_more_random_stuff.extension >test.txt

cat test.txt | awk -F '.' '{print $2 "." $3}'
extension_filename_more_random_stuff.extension

echo extension_filename_more_random_stuff >test2.txt
cat test2.txt | awk -F '_' '{print $2}'
filename
```

This, obviously, is merely an example of how to use this.

Answer (score 0):

**Command:**

```
e=$(echo 'myfile.java_HelloWorld_Created_2020-02-25-08-08-17_myfile.java' | cut -f 3 -d '.'); b=$(echo 'myfile.java_HelloWorld_Created_2020-02-25-08-08-17_myfile.java' | cut -f 2 -d '_'); echo $b.$e
```

**Explanation:**

In [cut](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html) command -d [delim] specifies which delimiter to use when cutting the text. -f [list] specifies which field(s) to choose

```
e=$(echo 'myfile.java_HelloWorld_Created_2020-02-25-08-08-17_myfile.java' | cut -f 3 -d '.')
```

In the above line, -d '.' divides the input into fields using . (dot) as delimiter. -f 3 picks the third field. Then the result is stored in the variable e.

The fields in this case are: 'myfile', 'java_HelloWorld_Created_2020-02-25-08-08-17_myfile', 'java'. The third field is 'java', therefore value 'java' is stored in the variable e.

```
b=$(echo 'myfile.java_HelloWorld_Created_2020-02-25-08-08-17_myfile.java' | cut -f 2 -d '_');
```

In the line above, -d '_' specifies that the input is to be divided into pieces using _ (underscore) as the delimiter. -f 2 takes the second field. The result is stored in the variable b.

The fields in this case are: 'myfile.java', 'HelloWorld', 'Created', '2020-02-25-08-08-17', 'myfile.java'. The second field is 'HelloWorld', therefore 'HelloWorld' is stored in the variable b.

```
echo $b.$e
```

prints variables b and e with . (dot) in-between. Since b='HelloWorld' and e='java', 'HelloWorld.java' is printed.

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Comment: I updated it. I think it should be understandable now.

Answer (score 0):

This example uses regex and `BASH_REMATCH` to pull capture groups from the regex.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

filename='myfile.java_HelloWorld_Created_2020-02-25-08-08-17_myfile.java'
regex='_([^_]+).*(\.[a-zA-Z]+)$'

if [[ $filename =~ $regex ]]; then
  echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
fi
# output: HelloWorld.java
```